# Turf laid just on topsoil?

Tags: landscaping, drainage, sod, topsoil, concrete

I have a new long garden raised path that has been built up both sides with concrete.

What happens if I just lay top soil on this & then turf. How much topsoil & should it be fertilised?

Will the turf survive with good watering - the border areas turfed are well sloped underneath for drainage?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you clarify please - are you saying you want to spread topsoil and turf on the path, or on the concrete part that's been built up? Can you add a photo or two of the area? lastly, what part of the world are you in?

Comment: you need to water sod, and personally I would use wood chips since you can grow edible mushrooms in them, and not worry about the grass as quickly

Comment: Thank you for your question; if could include an overall illustration, illustrations of the concrete features, dimensions of the path & concrete features, height of the raised path & concrete features above the adjacent ground surface, if surface of the path is concrete, if gravel for drainage, if drains, where intend to place the soil & turf, the adjacent soil type, the region, and if drainage conduit, the extent, dimensions & type, could be helpful. We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

I’m in London

Garden path laid on concrete with Smooth concrete sloping  sides down to existing lawn.

Top soil to be laid on top of sloping concrete then turf on top soil.

Will it work long term?

Will the grass eventually die even with good watering & phosphate fertiliser to aid grassroots growth & bonding with top soil?

Hope this helps.

Many thanks for your responses. Martin